# Fast column by column array division

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose that **M** and **N** are two Arrays. In simplest case, M and N like this:

> 1 14 7 80
>
> 2 15 8 12
>
> 3 16 9 11

(3 Rows and 4 Columns)

I want to **divide** column **1** by **All three Columns**, then divide column 2 by All three Columns and then divide column 3 by All three Columns.

**What is the fastest way to do it?** ( Surely, using for-loop is not a good algorithm. )

**EDIT:**

here is my for-loop code:

```
idx = 1;
for i = 1 : size(N,2)
   for j = 1 : size(M,2)
       u(:,idx)=N(:,i) ./ M(:,j);
       idx = idx + 1;
   end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "divide column one by all three columns"? It is not very clear. Perhaps if you update your post with your "slow" solution (using for loops) then we can show you how to write some faster code that does the same thing.

Comment: You said `M` and `N` are two arrays, but you've only shown and referred to one single array...?

Comment: So when you say "divide column 1 by All three Columns" you actually mean "divide all three other columns by column 1"? Because your description says the former but your code performs the latter... and again, you use 2 separate matrices but only ever refer to one, so can we assume that `M==N`? Why even have both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/permute.html)

Assuming `M` and `N` are same and equal to `A`

```
out = bsxfun(@rdivide, permute(A,[1 3 2]), A)
```

**Input:**

```
A =

 1    14     7    80
 2    15     8    12
 3    16     9    11
```

**Results for your Sample Input:**

```
out(:,:,1) =

1.0000    0.0714    0.1429    0.0125
1.0000    0.1333    0.2500    0.1667
1.0000    0.1875    0.3333    0.2727


out(:,:,2) =

14.0000    1.0000    2.0000    0.1750
7.5000    1.0000    1.8750    1.2500
5.3333    1.0000    1.7778    1.4545


out(:,:,3) =

7.0000    0.5000    1.0000    0.0875
4.0000    0.5333    1.0000    0.6667
3.0000    0.5625    1.0000    0.8182


out(:,:,4) =

80.0000    5.7143   11.4286    1.0000
6.0000    0.8000    1.5000    1.0000
3.6667    0.6875    1.2222    1.0000
```

Comment: Thank you, It's correct. Can you explain me about permute?

Comment: @RashidBagheri, added link for Doc.. take a look at it. :)

Comment: If you want to get back to the original 2D output that the OP code produces then you can either just call `out(:,:)` or else do it in one line `reshape(bsxfun(@rdivide, permute(A,[1 3 2]), A),3,[])`. I prefer this 3D version though.

Answer (score 3):

If

```
A = [1 14 7 80

     2 15 8 12

     3 16 9 11]
```

Then

```
bsxfun(@ldivide, prod(A,2), A).*A
```

returning

```
ans =

    0.0001    0.0250    0.0062    0.8163
    0.0014    0.0781    0.0222    0.0500
    0.0019    0.0539    0.0170    0.0255
```

So the idea is to just divide every element by ALL the other elements in that row (i.e. by the product of the row, `prod(A,2)`) and then just multiply back by the original number so cancel the fact that you've divided by it (i.e. the `.*A` at the end). So `ans(2,3)` above is `0.0222` which equals `(8/(2*15*8*12))*8` where `(2*15*8*12)` is the product of row 3.

**NOTE this answers the original question (i.e. the question you describe) and does *NOT* answer the question that your code implies**

Comment: Your question is anything but clear! Highly ambiguous.